# facebook one-login authentication

Tags: authentication, facebook

Im adding facebook one-login to my website. Just wanted to get some feedback from people who have already implemented it.

At the moment im allowing user to login to my site using fb:login, providing they have a valid account on fb and login successfully, if the same email address thats returned from fb matches my email address I hold in my own database, they will automatically be logged in to my site.

The problem I have is, im finding hard having just the email as my main authentication between the user and the my site. For those who have already implmented this, could you please share some of you loggic (theory) on how you autenticate the user when you're logging them onto your site.

Comment: Not understood your point that user gives its email id and you match with email id you hold and user given on fb? How you are doing login? Can you please explain? Are you not using fb:login?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Yes i am using fb:login, once the user logs  in using their fb account details, i have a getProfile method which obtains their's emailaddress. I then try to match fb's obtained emailaddress with the email address I have in my database.

The point is, is that what everyone else is doing or are there other checks one should perform such as look at other parameters, cookies etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem than you. I had users in my database with their name and email address and I wanted to add the Facebook connect plugin.

Now, on the login page, I let users choose between standard and Facebook login. If one choose Facbook login I retrieve his Facebook ID with the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)) :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(...);
$id = $facebook->getUser();
```

- If I have this Facebook ID in my records, I log the user in.
- If not, I retrieve his email adress :

  ```
  $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  $email   = $profile['email'];
  ```

  - If I have this email in my database, I store the facebook ID in that record (for the next time) and I log the user in.
  - If not, I create a new record with the Facebook ID and the email. After that, the user can set a password in his settings to be able to log in with the standard login (without Facebook).

You may want to check the [example of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) out to better understand how the flow works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any time :) You can contact me (via my profile) if you have any issue in the process. I've been there.

Answer (score 0):

I have also done this. I have now understood that you do you want to match the email address that if user changes his email address you want to update it. Its simple solution is that store the user information in your database. What I have done, I store the user profile id returned by the facebook as user name and by converting into `md5` I store the same profile ID as password and email adress returned by the user. Now every facebook user has its unique id in my database. Whenever user comes to my site and logins with facebook, There are two cases

1- I compare the profile id with my database and if record found I always update the email address in that particular field returned by facebook.. Now I can have the latest email address of the user. 
2- if the user is not in my database then I insert the record by applying the above method.

Hope it will help you

Comment: although this is not what i was looking for, thanks for sharing it as ive not even though about such eventualities and ill be implementing that too. What I want to know is, after the user logs in using their fb account details via fb:login, what do you do to check its the same user on your database other than checking their email address?

Comment: @david-l I simply check if the user is in my database then I dont compare email addresses, I just update that row against that user. If user is not in my database then I Insert his record in my database hainvg profile id as username, password and his email address